# PDF prevention to download on Google Apps Script

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

On Google Drive, users have the ability to prevent viewers to download PDF files. But I don't found it on Drive API for Google Apps Script(GAS).

Is there any way to enable it using GAS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in Apps Script if you enable the [Advanced Drive Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).
You can then make the following call:

```
Drive.Files.update({'labels': {'restricted': true}}, fileId);
```

This is per the documentation for the Drive API for the [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) call.

Answer (score 2):

I have investigated this in the past and it was not possible, I looked again today at both the Drive and DocList API through google script and its not possible still.

A cursory look at the DRIVE SDK does not indicate that is possible either.

What is the use case you are looking for? Many a time you can wrap the doc in a iframe on a Google site to prevent downloading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply man!
I need it because my users will use the Drive to see generated PDF, so I want to prevent download of them.